# UTF-8 response of TIdHTTPServer with Free Pascal

Tags: delphi, http, indy, freepascal, indy10

This code starts a HTTP server which listens for requests on port 8080. When compiled with Delphi 2009, the Chinese text is rendered correctly. With Free Pascal 2.6.0 however, the browser displays `ä¸­æ–‡` instead of `中文`.

What is the correct way to write Unicode / UTF-8 HTTP responses with Indy and Free Pascal?

```
program IdHTTPUnicode;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  IdHTTPServer, IdCustomHTTPServer, IdContext, IdSocketHandle, IdGlobal,
  SysUtils;

type
  TMyServer = class (TIdHTTPServer)
  public
    procedure InitComponent; override;
    procedure DoCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
      ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo;
      AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo); override;
  end;

procedure Demo;
var
  Server: TMyServer;
begin
  Server := TMyServer.Create(nil);
  try
    try
      Server.Active := True;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        WriteLn(E.ClassName + ' ' + E.Message);
      end;
    end;
    WriteLn('Hit any key to terminate.');
    ReadLn;
  finally
    Server.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyServer.InitComponent;
var
  Binding: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  inherited;

  Bindings.Clear;
  Binding := Bindings.Add;
  Binding.IP := '127.0.0.1';
  Binding.Port := 8080;
  Binding.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
end;

procedure TMyServer.DoCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
const
  UNI = '中文';
begin
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := '<html>' + UNI + '</html>';
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html';
  AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'UTF-8';
end;

begin
  Demo;
end.
```

In the debugger, I can see that different code in the method TIdIOHandler.Write is executed, for Free Pascal, STRING_IS_ANSI is defined:

```
procedure TIdIOHandler.Write(const AOut: string; AByteEncoding: TIdTextEncoding = nil
  {$IFDEF STRING_IS_ANSI}; ASrcEncoding: TIdTextEncoding = nil{$ENDIF}
  );
begin
  if AOut <> '' then begin
    AByteEncoding := iif(AByteEncoding, FDefStringEncoding);
    {$IFDEF STRING_IS_ANSI}
    ASrcEncoding := iif(ASrcEncoding, FDefAnsiEncoding, encOSDefault);
    {$ENDIF}
    Write(
      ToBytes(AOut, -1, 1, AByteEncoding
        {$IFDEF STRING_IS_ANSI}, ASrcEncoding{$ENDIF}
        )
      );
  end;
end;
```

Comment: what is `ASrcEncoding` on the entry of .Write ? Delphi 2009+ use UTF-16 for string and FPC 2.6 usually (but not always AFAIK) uses UTF-8

Comment: @Arioch'The ASrcEncoding is nil, which means that Write will use encOSDefault (which is Ansi on my Windows system). Are you sure that `string` is Unicode on Free Pascal 2.6.0? Some pages which I have checked indicate it still Ansi. So I guess the code will not work by using the ContentText property, I will need a bytestream.

Comment: For what i know it changed around 2.4 or 2.6 - and! it depends upon compiler options. At least by default on my Win7 x64 using recent CodeTyphon builds it is UTF-8 (but maybe it can be different for hieroglyph-based languages?).  (and speaking of encodings - there ain't such a thign as Unicode). Well, i think Indy is badly supported even on target Delphi and on FPC i'd even not tried to use it.... Try setting `FDefAnsiEncoding` to UTF-8 on FPC. And afair correct is lowcase "utf-8" by RFC.

Comment: also what values have AByteEncoding, FDefStringEncoding ?

Comment: AByteEncoding = TIdUTF8Encoding, FDefStringEncoding = TIdASCIIEncoding

Comment: then what happens inside `ToBytes` ? i think AByteEncoding is carried from `AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';` though. So what are bytes behind AOut ? not chars but bytes ? are they UTF-8 or not ? If they are, then like i said probably you have to be setting FDefAnsiEncoding to UTF-8 on FPC. And if you have options, then look if you can select better HTTP server components than INDY from CodeTyphon distro or maybe from mORMot project

Comment: AOut is `'<html>'#228#184#173#230#150#135'</html>'`, which seems to be the correct UTF-8 encoded string

Comment: @Arioch'The: "i think Indy is badly supported even on target Delphi" - why do you say that?

Comment: @Remy because for all the problems i saw in XE2 deiscussion i never heard "download updated release" but only heard "install SVN and try last development snapshot". When was Version 10.0.52 released ?

Comment: @Arioch'The: Indy doesn't really do "stable releases" anymore. Just SVN snapshots. We just don't have time or manpower to manage Indy releases "properly". Indy "releases" tend to be whatever SVN snapshots end up shipping with D/C/RAD IDE releases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FreePascal strings are not UTF-16 encoded like they are in Delphi 2009+.  In FreePascal, and in Delphi 2007 and earlier, your code needs to take the actual string encoding into account.  That is why Indy exposes additional Ansi-based parameters/properties for those platforms.

When `TIdHTTPServer` writes out the `ContentText` using `TIdIOHandler.Write()`, the `ASrcEncoding` parameter is not used on non-Unicode platforms, so you will have to use the `TIdIOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding` property instead to let `Write()` know what the encoding of the `ContentText` is, eg:

```
procedure TMyServer.DoCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
const
  UNI: WideString = '中文';
begin
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := UTF8Encode('<html>' + UNI + '</html>');
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html';

  // this tells TIdHTTPServer what to encode bytes to during socket transmission
  AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';

  // this tells TIdHTTPServer what encoding the ContentText is using
  // so it can be decoded to Unicode prior to then being charset-encoded
  // for output. If the input and output encodings are the same, the
  // Ansi string data gets transmitted as-is without decoding/reencoding...
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding := IndyUTF8Encoding;
end;
```

Or, more generically:

```
{$I IdCompilerDefines.inc}

procedure TMyServer.DoCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
const
  UNI{$IFNDEF STRING_IS_UNICODE}: WideString{$ENDIF} = '中文';
begin
  {$IFDEF STRING_IS_UNICODE}
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := '<html>' + UNI + '</html>';
  {$ELSE}
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := UTF8Encode('<html>' + UNI + '</html>');
  {$ENDIF}
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html';
  AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
  {$IFNDEF STRING_IS_UNICODE}
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding := IndyUTF8Encoding;
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

Comment: Many thanks for these solutions! I found that assigning IndyUF8Encoding to DefAnsiEncoding already fixes it. Using UTF8Encode() is not neccessary - it caused 'double-encoding' - so it looks like strings in Free Pascal are UTF-8 encoded at least with my compiler setting (-Mdelphi).

Comment: I don't see anything in FreePascal's documentation or wiki that says strings are UTF-8 encoded.  I see plenty of references that do say strings are Ansi, though. What compiler directive enables UTF-8 encoded strings? Putting FPC into Delphi mode alone shouldn't do that.

Comment: What is the difference between `DefAnsiEncoding := IndyUTF8Encoding` here and `DefAnsiEncoding := 'utf-8';` that i suggested ?

Comment: @mjn then do a check for string literals like i told in my answer. If string literals are UTF-8, you set `DefAnsiEncoding` to `utf-8`, if not then you don't. And i agree that enforcing UTF8Encode is questionable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it looks like Lazarus writes the UTF-8 encoded string constant - the source file is UTF-8 encoded - to the ContentText variable, which is a normal AnsiString. UTF8Encode will then be needed if the string is not coming from a UTF-8 source constant.

Comment: @Arioch'The: `DefAnsiEncoding` is a pointer to a `TIdTextEncoding` object. It is not a `String`. So you **cannot** assign `'utf-8'` to it. You have to use `IndyUTF8Encoding()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau and that object has some transcoding methods like .Net and Unicode Delphi TEncoding ?

Comment: @Arioch'The: yes, it is used for bytes<->string transcoding. In the current Indy release, `TIdTextEncoding` is an alias for `SysUtils.TEncoding` in Delphi 2009+, an alias for `System.Text.Encoding` in .NET, and a custom class that mirrors `SysUtils.TEncoding` in other versions/compilers. In the upcoming Indy release for XE4, it is now a new Indy-implemented interface that does not rely on `SysUtils.TEncoding` or `System.Text.Encoding` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In modern FreePascal strings by default are UTF-8 unless you tweaked copiler options.

Thus it seems in `iif(ASrcEncoding, FDefAnsiEncoding, encOSDefault);` the value of `encOSDefault` is wrong.
You may fix its detection in INDY sources if you like or i guess better would be to set `DefAnsiEncoding := 'utf-8';` (low-case by RFC AFAIR)

To be on safe side you can check for UTF-8 mode at the program beginning. Set some non-Latin constant (like that chinese thing, or greek or cyrillic - whatever) and check if it is UTF8 or not: http://compaspascal.blogspot.ru/2009/03/utf-8-automatic-detection.html

However overall i think you may try to find some library that cares about FPC and Linux more than Indy. Indy seems to me stagnating and next to abandoned even on Delphi. Maybe `Synopse mORMot` (look for DataSnap performance tests article) can help you or some library that comes with `CodeTyphon` distro.

Comment: `iif(ASrcEncoding, FDefAnsiEncoding, encOSDefault);` first checks if `ASrcEncoding` is nil. If so, then it checks if `FDefAnsiEncoding` is nil. If so, then it returns `IndyOSDefaultEncoding`. If `string` is Ansi and is UTF-8 encoded, then either `ASrcEncoding` or `IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding` needs to be set to `IndyUTF8Encoding`, not `'utf-8'` since they are `TIdTextEncoding` objects and not string values.

Comment: What makes you think that "Indy seems to me stagnating and next to abandoned even on Delphi"?  Indy is actively developed, is about to release a new version with the upcoming Delphi/C++Builder/RADStudio XE4 release, and is even getting ready to start work on Indy 11 in the near future.

Comment: Strings are not UTF-8 in FPC, but default 1-byte system encoding (meaning ANSI on Windows). Lazarus stuffs utf8 in them anyway though

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort, do you have fresh installation of Lazarus in Windows ? I do... as i wrote above it IS UTF-8

Comment: @RemyLebeau many reports of its next to unusable state in XE2 and the project site only told about downloading SVN and tring to compile it thsi way or another. So, after XE4 release Indy gonna release too? Good news. But even JVCL makes releases more often.

Comment: Arioch: Lazarus stuff utf8 in strings not meant to be utf8 for visual purposes. But you didn't say Lazarus, you said Free Pascal. Free Pascal doesn't significantly use utf8.

Comment: You meant "necessarily" ? maybe you're right. But what i can observe: me and topic starter do have FPC installed on our Win7 boxes and we both observe String to be UTF-8. And there are some people who DO NOT have FPC installed but tell us not to believe our own eyes and instead rely on some potentially outdated or incorrect articles. And when the questions comes which {$ pragme defines if AnsiString is UTF-8 or MBCS - there is no answer on that! Actually as i need to make one lib compilable with both new Delphi (string is UTF-16), old one (MBCS) and FPC (UTF-8) i'd be glad to know such pragma

Comment: @Arioch'The I only observed UTF-8 string constants in the source file are simply copied to the (AnsiString) string variable.

Comment: @mjn you can test it using code like `var as: AnsiString; ws: WideString; ws := WideChar(word-constant) + WideChar(word-constant) + WideChar(word-constant)...; as := ws; var b: boolean := IsUTF8(as);`

Comment: @Arioch'The: the upcoming XE4 release will ship with Indy 10.6.0 included, which is a semi-significant release because much of Indy's internals had to be updated to accommodate the new iOS mobile compiler. They are mostly internal changes, although there are some public changes (like the `TIdTextEncoding` class is now an `IIdTextEncoding` ref-counted interface), which is why Indy is still at 10.x and not 11.0 yet.

Comment: @RemyLeveau - good luck to them then, perhaps that would be a worth release, full of glory. But as of current state i'm sceptical towards Indy. But i wish them best.